# Regex to parse wrongly formatted unordered list

Tags: html, regex, markup

I'm dealing with a website migration. Unfortunately the unordered list elements on the old website are formatted without using the `ul` tag. So I would like to parse the following wrong markup to a common html `ul` markup:

```html
<p class="bodytext">
 •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is some random text.<br>
 •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is some other random text.<br>
 •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is another random text.
</p>
```

**Important facts:**

- We are in the context of a post element, so there are a lot of bodytext classes
- The last list element has no br tag
- All list elements have this "bull" and 3x "&nbsp"
- The amount of list elements is variable

I thought about a regex but I have no idea to tackle the mentioned problems, especially how to "detect" where to replace  and how to match the last list item without

Any help would be appreciatted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: Lot's of manual work you have here. 1. Replace all `<p class="bodytext">` with `<ul>`. Use PHPStorm to auto-edit ending tag. 2. Replace all `dot&nbsp;` to `<li>` and append `</li>` to end of line (again use editor with multi-edit feature)

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, parse HTML with regexp [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

If you understand this, and still want to continue using regexp, you can do something like this:

**1. Inserting the `<ul></ul>` tags:**

regexp:

```
(<p class="bodytext">)(.+?)(<\/p>)
```

replace with:

```
<ul>\2</ul>
```

Gives

```
<ul>
    •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is some random text.<br>
    •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is some other random text.<br>
    •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is another random text.
</ul>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/3GCTsO/1/)

**2. Inserting the `<li></li>` tags**

Regexp:

```
(•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; )(.+?)(<br>|)(\n)
```

Replace with:

```
<li>\2</li>\n
```

Gives:

```
<ul>
    <li>This is some random text.</li>
    <li>This is some other random text.</li>
    <li>This is another random text.</li>
</ul>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/7ncWuc/1/)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion, how to solve that without regex?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two steps:

1. Use pattern: `<([^ ?]+).*>((?=[^<]*•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;)[\w\W]+)<\/(\1)>`.

`<([^ ?]+).*>` and `<\/(\1)>` assure that you will have matching tags (opening and closing), thanks to backreference to first capturing group: `\1`.

It will match only elements that contains the list thanks to positive lookahead: 
`(?=[^<]*•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mm5TE2/1)

In second capturing group, you'll have all list elements, so you can replace it with: `<ul>\2</ul>`. Now you'll have something like this:

```
<ul>
  •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is some random text.<br>
  •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is some other random text.<br>
  •&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This is another random text.
</ul>
```

2. Replace all occurences of `•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` with `<li>`